# Why mongoose store my number as Double

Tags: mongoose, numbers, double

I try to understand why when I save a model containing a `customId` as `number` (for example `61528564963650091`), it keeps saving it as a Double type:

`61528564963650091.0`

If the number is small, it creates a Int32

To solve my problem, I tried to use `Long` type but it was worse...

Schema example:

```
{
  customId: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  }
}
```

If someone can light me up on this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max value of 32 bit integer is ~ `4 290 000 000`, as you can see, you really cannot fit ther the `61 528 564 963 650 091`.

Its not about mongo, its just the limitation of 32 bits.

Double is usually 64 bit implementation (thats why it is called `double=2x32`), which means it allows much bigger number to be saved as the one you have provided.

---

If I look to the newest mongoose docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html it looks like it does not support "Long" (also have in mind that Javascript has only one type - number - which is 64 bit floating point)

---

But there is solution - you can use this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-long

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I totally forgot about the Max 32bits value :/... I used Long plugin but it makes the code complicated when you want to compare value for example